# Performe, navigate, to child view from App Delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm trying to open child view(PostReaderViewController, the fourth view on Image ) when application is lunched through Push notification It's. Storyboard Image :
[image]
This is my Code :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
      ... 
    //Detecting if the app was lunched by clicking on push notification :
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [launchOptions valueForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"];
    NSDictionary *apsInfo = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];

    if(apsInfo) {
        UIStoryboard *mainstoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        PostReaderViewController* postReader = (PostReaderViewController *)[mainstoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"postReaderView"];
        CostumSDPost *tempPost = [[CostumSDPost alloc] init];
        tempPost.ID = userInfo[@"post_id"];
        postReader.thePost = tempPost;
        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:postReader animated:YES completion:NULL];
        //userInfo[@"post_id"]);
    }
    return YES;
}
```

When I launch my APP via push notification no error are shown but unfortunly it start and show the default View (third View on image). 
Note that I'm using [SWRevealMenu](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) and the Intial Point (first View on image) is the Reveal View Controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To slove This issue :

**First** I've created Global BOOL variable then in the AppDelegate I set this var to YES  if app is lunched via push notif like this :

```
//Detecting if the app was lunched by clicking on push notification :
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [launchOptions valueForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"];
    NSDictionary *apsInfo = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
    if(apsInfo) { 
        // Set my global Var to YES
        GlobalSingleton *global = [GlobalSingleton sharedInstance];
        global.displayFirstPost = YES; }
```

**Then** In my Home screen I check if this variable == YES then navigate to next screen auto else show the Home screen :

```
GlobalSingleton *global = [GlobalSingleton sharedInstance];
             if (global.displayFirstPost) {
                 // NAvigation code to the third Screen
                 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`self.window.rootViewController` needs to perform the presentation in either `viewDidLoad` or in `viewDidAppear`.  If you do it earlier then either `rootViewController` will be `nil` or the view controller hierarchy won't be in a state that can accommodate a presentation.